# can we use visualstudio 2010 soucecode in visualstudio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2019

my client using visualstudio 2010 for his application and app OS version is windows 7. they shared the sourcecode of that application and asked me to migrate that code into VSTS. but, i am using visualstudio 2019 with OS version windows 2010 in my system. can we use that sourcecode in my system. any compatabilities are there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as visual studio 2010 source code. THere is source code, that has been written in VIsual Studio, but a .cs file is a .cs file, regardless of the editor. A text file is a text file. Source code is not like word, where there are a ton of formatting information embedded in a file format that is complex - source code are SIMPLE text files.

2010 to 2019 MAY be a little large for the project file - you have to try it out. That being said, making new project files is trivial.

2010 likely (not sure, it is like ages ago) does not use nuget - you likely run into more problems with .NET versions and links to third party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you will most likely have to adjust for the target runtimes/frameworks and configuration differences that the VSProject file will have between the versions. The VSProject file will almost certainly migrated to the latest version for VS2019.

You may not be able to if the target runtime/framework for the application is not supported by VS2019. For example, if it something less than .NET 4.5.2, you may run into problems.

The best solution is for you to get his system, his version of VS and the code base updated to the latest. If this will be a significant effort on your part, tell your client that migration will be a billable item.

If you're merely trying to share code, write, but not build anything you can certainly use VS2019, but at that rate, you may as well us VS Code.

Comment: This is the trouble with legacy projects. Migrating may be opening a can of worms or could be painless.

Comment: Me and my client are in different locations. so, i can't get his system. anyway, Thanks for your solution and suggestion.